# Validating and Sending CKEditor Content in a Form

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am working on including a CKEditor on my website, and I need to check if the content of a specific  (with id="editor") is empty before submitting the form.

How can I check if the Editor-Div is empty, preferably with PHP-only?

Here is my form code:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <ul class="login">
        <li>...</li>
        <li>
            <!-- Left out some unimportant things here -->
            <div id="editor" placeholder="Schreibe hier dein Text...">
            </div>
        </li>
        
        <li>
            <input type="submit" name="Send" value="Abschicken">
        </li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

And here is my code for validating the input:

```
if (isset($_GET['mode']) && $_GET['mode'] == 'success') {
    echo "<br>";
    echo success('Emails erfolgreich gesendet!');
} else {
    if (empty($_POST) === false)  {
        if (empty($_POST['subject']) === true || trim($_POST['subject']) == "") {
            $errors[] = 'Ein Thema ist Pflicht';
        }

        if (empty($_POST['body']) === true || trim($_POST['body']) == "") {
            $errors[] = 'Eine Nachricht ist Pflicht';
        }
        
        if (empty($errors) === false) {
            echo "<br>" . output_errors($errors);
        } else {
            
            //email('MyEMailAddress', $_POST['subject'], $_POST['body'], 'roundmail');
            //mail_users($_POST['subject'], $body);
            //echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; URL=index.php?section=Rundmail&mode=success'>";
            //laden();
            
            exit();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `name="editor"` to your form element and then it should be on your `$_POST['editor']`

So if you named your text_area editor you can get it from POST and after that you can check it using php.